# Why does my SAMLresponse received from ADFS not contain any claims?

Tags: passport.js, saml-2.0, adfs, claims-based-identity

I have setup ADFS and a NodeJS application to perform single-sign-on using ADFS as IdP.

I receive the SAMLreponse seen below.

When I receive the profile-object inside the verify function setup for the SAML-strategy, I see this:

```
{"issuer":"http://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/services/trust"}
```

I need the profile to include at least the email or user ID of the logged in user.

How can I fix this?

SAMLresponse received:

```
<samlp:Response Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified"
    Destination="https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse" ID="_e543e979-0d99-48fe-947f-1d1469da8c70"
    InResponseTo="_49ab1e1060c3d7849902" IssueInstant="2018-06-28T19:46:27.782Z" Version="2.0"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/></samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_cf245f57-1380-47cd-a5d3-05b13e4d9416" IssueInstant="2018-06-28T19:46:27.782Z"
        Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://nonp-adfs.dsgapps.dk/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_cf245f57-1380-47cd-a5d3-05b13e4d9416">
                    <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>r6voAsVq4yAJTn4BQLFsyaoiCK3b7KQbJ5jVqi53ceY=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>F55JA6jNp3qFfp7p/BSzQBRTtVPOlQvIfVNG3JiqjohVC7Et0+aiRVlHHvZNghPJxhmxhuAUbo2kOweN+lZKb+fqDgK51kZ/DrIVpkljmwP2gJYgOGpJti53wfH2qkdDsxNkR3e13mG7RKwBuA4gJ0NxUFshmxyun0HKefd10wjnFwHY6dELWFmTL1W5xd2ZF/98ahIaqEWAMCYsJewEg4ND8z4vG74miht3lWHfTJL6kQ0UGkTJVwGZy9L8zaY8AMDRujs8SlXvBx9nvUnvufpYqto4kd0O0USWMCOPipcF2sVYDOVzidRSRb79TK256Wg9EGiw1usVThfAJ8IBzQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <Subject>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_49ab1e1060c3d7849902"
                NotOnOrAfter="2018-06-28T19:51:27.782Z" Recipient="https://localhost:3000/adfs/postResponse"/></SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2018-06-28T19:46:27.781Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-06-28T20:46:27.781Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>acme_tools_com</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-06-28T19:45:51.797Z">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Comment: Have you added claims rules in ADFS?

Comment: Probably not. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. From the Relying Party Trust Menu I could add the claims such as AD properties.